# Better way to convert a 2D list to 1D list of grouped values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a integer list:

```
[[2, 8], [3, 10, 1], [4], [], [3, 8], [2, 5], [1, 5], [1, 6]]
```

I want to convert it to string list:

```
['28', '3101', '4', '', '38', '25', '15', '16']
```

Notice elements of child list are grouped together.
I have written this code and it works:

```
    def convert_list(listvalues):
        converted_list = []
        i = ""
        for item in listvalues:
            for val in item:
                i = i + str(val)
            j = i
            i = ""
            converted_list.append(j)
        return converted_list

    values = [[2, 8], [3, 10, 1], [4], [], [3, 8], [2, 5], [1, 5], [1, 6]]
    l = convert_list(values)
    print(l)
```

output is:

```
['28', '3101', '4', '', '38', '25', '15', '16']
```

is there any better way to do it, like with map function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.join`:

```
l = [[2, 8], [3, 10, 1], [4], [], [3, 8], [2, 5], [1, 5], [1, 6]]
["".join(map(str, i)) for i in l]
```

Output:

```
['28', '3101', '4', '', '38', '25', '15', '16']
```

Or `str.zfill`:

```
["".join(["0%s" % j for j in i]) for i in l]
```

Output:

```
['0208', '0301001', '04', '', '0308', '0205', '0105', '0106']
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris, this works. if I need ```['0208', '0301001', '04', '', '0308', '0205', '0105', '0106']``` would I do ```'0'.join``` in this case it gives 208 instead of 0208

Comment: No. `str.join` is when you want to _join_ its input; `'0'.join(["2", "8"])` will return `"208"`. What you want is to add prefixing `"0"`, check the update.